# Bubble sort with structures in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a structure consisting of one element  char a[50]. When I want to sort them using bubble sort

```
struct ccircular {
    char a[50];
};
```

Items

```
struct ccircular *aux;
aux=(struct ccircular *)malloc(num*(sizeof(struct ccircular)));
```

Function

```
void ordenar(struct ccircular *aux,int num)
{
    struct ccircular temp;
    struct ccircular *orden;
    orden=aux;
    int i,j;
    for (i=1;i<num;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<num;j++)
        {
            if(orden[j].a>orden[j+1].a)
            temp=orden[j];
            orden[j]=orden[j+1];
            orden[j+1]=temp;    
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to sort an array of `struct circular`s by the string they contain. In C, yu cannot compare strings with relative oerators, so `orden[j].a > orden[j+1].a` will compare the adresses, which in your case are the adresses of the struct. They are already in order. Use `strcmp`.

Comment: That algorithm implementation is wrong. The limit on the `j` loop should be `j=0; j<(num-i); ++j` . And regardless your missing `{ }` wrapping the element exchange logic. Finally, `order` is utterly pointless; just use `aux`.

Comment: (You also go out of bounds by accessing the element `j + 1`, which might be `num`.)

Comment: You might want to consider using the standard function `qsort()`.

Comment: Yes
but I won't implement the qsort to struct
how?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the function [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare two strings together, this isn't possible in C with <> operators.

I've used an optimized algorithm, where the loop stops until no more swaps are necessary; that's because it often happens, that in one pass, more than one element pair is swapped. Detailed explanation: [Wikipedia Bubblesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

The first time, the loop runs through without swapping an element, it is complete and stops

```c
void ordenar(struct ccircular *aux, int num) {
    int i;
    bool swapped = false;
    struct ccircular temp;

    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (i = 0; i < (num-1); ++i) {
            if (strcmp(aux[i].a, aux[i+1].a) > 0) {
                temp = aux[i];
                aux[i] = aux[i+1];
                aux[i+1] = temp;

                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        num--;
    } while (swapped == true);
}
```